# Deleting an item in a foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, reference, unset

I have a foreach loop where I want to unset an item from an array if certain conditions are met, like this:

```
foreach ($array as $element) {
    if (conditions) {
        unset($element);
    }
}
```

But the element is not unset after that. What am I doing wrong? Am I unsetting a reference to the actual element or something like that?

Comment: Do you care if the index is still set? `$array[4]=NULL !== !isset($array[4])`

Comment: `unset` does 2 different things. If you had used `foreach($array as &$element)` (note the ampersand), then you would have replaced the value with null, which is the other behavior than the one you may be after: removing the item from the array entirely, without a trace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple Solution, unset the element by it's index:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $element) {
    if (conditions) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Just unsetting `$element` will not work, because this variable is not a reference to the arrays element, but a copy. Accordingly changing the value of `$element` will not change the array too.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method, you can pass the array element into the loop by reference by doing the following:

```
foreach($array as &$var) {
    unset($var);
}
```

This is useful because you then have direct access to the array element to change or delete as you wish without having to construct a new array or accessing by key. Any changes you make to $var affects the contents of $array.

Comment: This will just unset the reference, not the original element.